# I have a weird and strange intermittent error when uploading files and it only appears on the deployment server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I get this error randomly, sometimes it shows and sometimes not!

**The Error:**

Now it disappeared :S! but it will appear within the next hours!
Simply, It states that the parametrized query need a parameter '@PorfilePic' which was not supplied, although that it's supplied and the website works locally and also works on the server. I don't change the code, the provider doesn't change any settings.

I was told that I exceed my memory limit for the AppPool which is 250 MB but I think it should it appear once I exceed and after the pool rests it should work normally. but this is was the case a week ago. now it just works randomly for hours and randomly shows this error! so I hope maybe someone got the same error and could help to figure it out.

Btw, this is a shared windows hosting account. and I spoke with my providers, Honestly I think they are good in everything (Seriosuly) but in everything other than finding this specific error! :D

**The Code:**

```
.Aspx Page:

<li>
    Profile Picture:
    <asp:FileUpload ID="ProfilePic_Upld" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" /><br />
</li>
```

---

**Code Behind File:**

```
if (ProfilePic_Upld.HasFile)
{
    string fileType = ProfilePic_Upld.PostedFile.ContentType;

    if (fileType == "image/bmp" || fileType == "image/gif" || fileType == "image/jpeg" || fileType == "image/png")
    {
        if (ProfilePic_Upld.PostedFile.ContentLength <= 10485760)
        {
            string ppFileName = ProfilePic_Upld.PostedFile.FileName;
            string savedFileName = newCruise.Name + "_pp" + ppFileName.Substring(ppFileName.IndexOf('.'));
            string cruisePpUploadPath = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cruisesPpUploadPath"].ToString());
            ProfilePic_Upld.SaveAs(cruisePpUploadPath + savedFileName);
            newCruise.ProfilePic = savedFileName;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    newCruise.ProfilePic = "default.jpeg";
}
```

---

**Web.config (ApplicationSettings Part):**

```
<appSettings>
<add key="cruisesPpUploadPath" value="~\resouces\cruises\cruise_pp\" />
<add key="cruisesDpUploadPath" value="~\resouces\cruises\cruise_dp\" />
<add key="cruisesClUploadPath" value="~\resouces\cruises\cruise_cl\" />
<add key="cruiseItinerariesPpUploadPath" value="~\resouces\cruises\itineraries\iti_pp\" />
<add key="cruiseItinerariesMapsUploadPath" value="~\resouces\cruises\itineraries\iti_maps\" />
<add key="cruiseReviewDocumentsUploadPath" value="~\resouces\cruises\reviews\" />

</appSettings>
```

---

**Cruise Class (newCruise)**

```
public class Cruise
{
    public int ID
    { get; set; }

    public string Name
    { get; set; }

    public int CountryID
    { get; set; }

    public string ProfilePic
    { get; set; }

    public string Description
    { get; set; }

    public int OfficialRate
    { get; set; }

}
```

**DAL Methode for creating new cruise**

```
    public static int AddNewCruise(Cruise NewCruise)
    {
        string commandText = "INSERT INTO Cruises (Name, CountryID, ProfilePic, Description, OfficialRate) VALUES (@Name, @CountryID, @ProfilePic, @Description,  @OfficialRate); SELECT scope_identity();";
        int newCruiseId;

        Cruise newCruise = NewCruise;
        string name = newCruise.Name;
        int countryId = newCruise.CountryID;
        string profilePic = newCruise.ProfilePic;
        string desc = newCruise.Description;
        int officialRate = newCruise.OfficialRate;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryID", countryId);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfilePic", profilePic);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", desc);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficialRate", officialRate);

                connection.Open();

                newCruiseId = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());


                return newCruiseId;
            }
        }
    }
```

N.B I'm running out of my deadline, so if anyone think that this is a problem with the server I hope you could suggest some good windows shared hosting providers.

N.B (2) The pictures that I upload doesn't exceed 1 MB!

N.B (3) Guys, please this is a very important note. The website is working without any errors right now, and however you're right about handling the uploaded file (which btw I updated to include else blocks for the Size and File Type if conditions by providing an error message and then return;) but the actual problem is that I use the same code, same website, same server and iis settings. so same application, and I also update the same image but I get the error randomly. this can't be about the file handling! I upload a jpg image of size 105 KB. one day it works, the other day it won't! so however you're totally right about handling the file and I already followed your advice as this is a defect in my system, but this is not the cause of the problem. I really wish it could be that simple!

### Conclusion:

First of all the problem was that I'm testing when developing on my personal PC where I use Firefox, Then Me and the client follow up on the work from our business PCs which uses Internet Explorer. the problem was in not handling the two conditions for the size and the type, so I don't accept the uploaded file but I still call the database methode, so this was the first step. then I just followed the advise and returned whenever any of the conditions are not met, so I upload the same picture to two different instances of my application (one opened from IE and another from FireFox). Firfox uploads fine but IE now display type error. I did a little research and turns out that IE receive jpg and png as progressive types (PJPEG and X-PNG) so by adding in my type condition image/jpeg and image/x-png everything works fine.

Thanks for your time, Much appreciated =). I hope this question helps, I don't if this is a famous thing in IE but for me I think it's weird and I believe that other people are looking into the same issue!

Comment: Whoever voted for my question, if you have the same error we should talk! :S lol .. Guys, can you believe that I've been living this myth for more than a week!

Comment: Can you post the whole exception with exact message and stack trace? What is `newCruise` in your code?

Comment: You mention the error is around `@PorfilePic` - but no code is shown that seems to relate to that...?

Comment: Code seems to have nothing to do with the miniscule error information given. Whoever upvoted this question didn't read it, methinks.

Comment: Ok newCruise is an object from my class, and @ProfilePic is the parameter in the DAL query. anyway I'll add the Class code and the DAL methode now. and I agree with Andrew, I think it's not code related because it works then stops, then appears! .. I can't post the exact error right now because sadly it's working right now. But I'll try to also include this whenever I get the error again or I'l try to find a screenshot that I've took for the error.

Comment: I did not say it was not code related; I said it was not related to the code you posted. and it turns out: I was wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`It states that the parametrized query need a parameter '@PorfilePic' which was not supplied1`

This to me, indicates that you are storing the name/path of the uploaded file to a database, and the value it is attempting to insert (at that time) is a null string.

**Edit**

Looking at the code, if the file type or file size conditions are not met, then it is possible that `newCruise.ProfilePic` will not be set, resulting in a possible null reference.

(It's hard to tell without the code for the `newCruise` class.)

```
if (fileType == "image/bmp" || fileType == "image/gif" || fileType == "image/jpeg" || fileType == "image/png")
{
    if (ProfilePic_Upld.PostedFile.ContentLength <= 10485760)
    {
```

**Edit**

Based on your DAL code. It is definitely possible for what I describe above to occur.

If the file type does not match your conditions or the file size is too large, the code will cause the exception mentioned. (If, it calls the `AddNewCruise` method regardless of the out come of the conditions)

I suggest performing some validation on the `Cruise` object before persisting it.

At the very least you should not be invoking `AddNewCruise` method, if the file type and size conditions above have not been satisfied, without providing some default values (such as `newCruise.ProfilePic = "default.jpeg";`).

Comment: I'm sorry the problem is very complicated to me so I forgot to include some important details. anyway, the mechanism that I use is to store the Directory in web.config AppSettings part, and the file name in the db. actually it's working fine locally so I don't think that the DAL isn't not getting the FileName neither the PL is not sending or reading the FileName correctly. but maybe the I run out of memory or execution time so it quite a part of the code or something and end up with a null. because as you can see, if the FileUpload is empty it will set it to default

Comment: Which means that if the value is null, then it passed the If statement which checks if the FileUpload control has file or not, then the problem with the upload occurs.

Comment: Ok but I'm sure about the file type and the size (per my new note). and I already updated my question. also note that I've debugged this application locally and it worked just fine.

Comment: Regarding your last edit, I don't think that this might be the cause but I totally agree with you and I'm sure that this will make me face problems in the future. so I'll try to update my PL and research on memory leakage because everybody think that this might be the casue!

Comment: @lKashef I don't know who that "everybody" would be... but you seem to have a much clearer issue here than a nebulous "memory leak", which is extremely unlikely to cause the exception you are getting.

Comment: I was referring to the support agents and their admins but they didn't confirm that. Well, I'm not the one to give an advice or an opinion here but please check my last note (3). This is close to madness! I can't believe what on earth could be causing a web application to display an error that is working locally, and remotely on the server! but sometimes it just decide to give me this error. through my little experience I've learned that an error won't appear for no reason but I'm dying to know the reason!

Comment: Finally solved the issue, starting from the point that you have discussed here. please check my last edit for details

Answer (score 0):

jdavies is right on about your problem, but maybe isn't getting it across clearly.

It has nothing to do with server memory leaks or limits, and nothing to do with production/development.

It's because you don't properly handle the case when someone uploads a file that is *not* an image. In that case, you never set the profile pic property to anything. Therefore, it is null, resulting in exactly the error you are receiving.

Comment: It's really not that complicated: find a path in your code where the profile pic path is not being set or is set to null. This has *nothing* to do with app pool memory limits.

Comment: and btw; your code has more flaws... such as not properly handling if someone uploads a file with the same name as an existing file.

Comment: Ok, how can I debug a website that's already has been deployed ? when I run the website on the local machine it never creates this error!
and about the flaws, I'm really not that good so I am that you're pointing me to these points, but for this specific point of the duplicate file name, if you check you'll see that I name the saved file after the entered cruise name which I restrict to be unique.

Comment: In the first place, you need to start with an *accurate* and *complete* error report. Aren't errors being logged on the server? Don't tell me the user seeing an asp.net raw error screen is your only debugging tool...

Comment: and I'm fairly sure you aren't checking your unique constraint at the proper time... but that's just a guess from what I've seen so far.

Comment: Actually all what I have is the raw error page, I enabled the debugging and it shows the error as it appears on my local machine. I've tried a lot to request a remote debugging access but the provider don't agree on that. so is there's a way to monitor my website error when I'm stuck with a shared hosting account ? actually I'm still working on some important functions but for the unqiue constraint I use a database constraint, so it will never add the cruise to the database if the name already exists and I made sure of that.

Comment: I really want to thank you for your time because I'm sure there's something doable about this and maybe you'll figure out while thinking about this. If you need any further clarification please ask me and if you're free I don't mind sending you the code so you'd test it.

Comment: The problem is, you save the file before you ever touch the database, so your database coonstraint will have no effect whatsoever. Which actually causes yet another bug...

Comment: Ok, I just have two questions. 1) are you suggesting that this might be the problem ? 2) what's the code that you suggest I should use to upload my files, because I just used common sense with a very basic code sample that just illustrates how to use the methods of the FileUpload Control, so if you use a code or you have something in mind I'd really appreciate it.